# CloudFormation ElasticIP Parameter

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, openvpn, elastic-ip

I have a CloudFormation template which adds **OpenVPN** to an existing VPC and requires an Elastic IP allocation ID as a parameter.  It also adds the public IP address from the same Elastic IP to the OpenVPN instance configuration (in it's `UserData` section).

I've currently implemented this as 2 parameters *(using made-up defaults)* i.e.

```
Parameters:

  ElasticIpAddress:
    Description: >-
      IP Address of an Elastic IP.
    Type: String
    Default: 53.176.52.215

  ElasticIpAllocationId:
    Description: >-
      Allocation id of the same Elastic IP to associate OpenVPN server with.
    Type: String
    Default: eipalloc-f2013ba5

  ...
```

> **NOTE** - Both of these must point to the same ElasticIP in AWS!

The `ElasticIpAddress` parameter is used when creating the **OpenVPN** instance in a `AWS::EC2::Instance` section as follows: -

```
openVPN:
  Type: 'AWS::EC2::Instance'
  Properties:
    Tags:
      - Key: Name
        Value: openVPN server
    UserData:
      Fn::Base64: !Sub |
        public_hostname=${ElasticIpAddress}
        admin_user=${OpenVPNASAdminUser}
    ...
```

... and the `ElasticIpAllocationId` get used in an `AWS::EC2::EIPAssociation` section ...

```
IPAssoc:
  Type: 'AWS::EC2::EIPAssociation'
  Properties:
    AllocationId: !Ref ElasticIpAllocationId
    InstanceId: !Ref openVPN
  DependsOn: openVPN
```

It seems very redundant to have (a) *allocation ID* and (b) *IP address* of the same Elastic IP!

My main question is - does a function exists which: -

1. Retrieve the IP address from an Elastic IP allocation Id *or*
2. Retrieve an allocation Id from an IP address of an elastic IP?

My gut feeling is that I'll have to use the CLI inside the `UserData:` section of the instance and use AWS CLI commands - not sure how nicely that will work with the OpenVPN AMI as it currently just takes OpenVPN specific configuration.

Any advice is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The right way to achieve what you want, is to create a R53 record, for example vpn.mydomain.com which points to your Elastic IP address (A record).
You can then assign this record in userdata instead of ${ElasticIpAddress}, and eliminate the need for the IP address parameter.

```
public_hostname=vpn.mydomain.com
```

As long as your EIP is updated on the R53 record, you should be good.
This is also helpful if you need to change the EIP address, you still have control over the record on your deployed instance via Route53.

[Getting Started with Route53](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/getting-started.html)

Comment: My VPC template creates an Elastic IP and my OpenVPN template assigns it via the 2 parameters.  Are u saying update my VPC template so that I take a Route53 hosted zone as a parameter and a record (defaults e.g. to `vpn`) which then creates a recordset linking the ElasticIP to the DNS (e.g. via a `AWS::Route53::RecordSet`).  Still assuming my OpenVPN template will still have to have 2 parameters i.e. (a) The FQDN (e.g. vpn.mysite.com) which updates the OpenVPN config via the `UserData` section and (b) the ElasticIP allocation Id (which the open OpenVPN instance will be associated with)?

Comment: Your VPC template should create the VPC + Hosted Zone, and your OpenVPN stack should create the instance and EIP + r53 record. If you don’t like the parameters, look into nested stacks or output export/import.